# Change the default hover option from blue to custom in a Django form? (Select2)

Tags: html, css, django, select, jquery-select2

I've been trying to change the color from the dropdowns from the default browser (blue, now gray on EDGE) to something else and I've tried everything including Select2 and cannot get it to work...The selects are generated from the database from Django.

Made progress by changing the buttons once they're clicked but cannot change the hover from the default blue and gray for Edge to something else.

```
select option:hover,
    select option:focus,
    select option:active {
        background: linear-gradient(#000000, #000000);
        background-color: #000000 !important;
        color: gray !important;
    }

    select option:checked {
        background: linear-gradient(yellow, yellow);
        background-color: yellow !important; 
        color: white;
    }
```

Here's the HTML for the selects:

```
                        {% for f in select_form %}
                            <tr>
                                <th>{{ f.label_tag }} </th>
                                <td>{{ f }}</td>
                            </tr>
                        {% endfor %}
```

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVUij.png)

I tried adding a CSS property for the select2 but no effect:

```
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single:hover {
  background-color: yellow !important; /* Change to your desired hover color */
  color: #fff; /* Change text color if needed */
}
```

Do I somehow have to set a property in the Django form for a class to get a select2 property or what approach can I take since I cannot directly access the HTML code? Please help.

Comment: Could you show us the generated HTML, after Django's translation of {{ }} tags ?

Comment: @chatours I've added an example image of the HTML that's generated or you do you mean the code itself? Because that I cannot seem to find.

Comment: Seeing the code would help. In your browser, right click on the dropdown and choose "Inspect element".

Comment: @chatours 

Found this once I inspect the dropdown:

<select name="hub" class="form-control" id="id_hub">
 <option value selected> --------- </option>
 <option value="1"> rename me </option>
</select>

Answer (score 0):

You've probably stumbled on this already, but customizing HTML `<option>` is not that easy. Explanations on [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7208786/how-to-style-the-option-of-an-html-select-element).

A few options are available as workarounds, select2 is one of them, using JS. According to the [docs](https://select2.org/getting-started/basic-usage), you have to be able to use a selector to catch the `<select>` tags you want to customize. You can explicitly choose a selector, for example a class, and make sure Django passes it:

```py
# forms.py

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ...
    my_select = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset = MyObject.objects.all(),
        widget = forms.Select(attrs = {"class":"mySelectorForSelect2"})
    )
```

will render as `<select class='mySelectorForSelect2'>`. So, you could add

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mySelectorForSelect2').select2();
});
```

to your JS.

Another option, which requires more work but gives you freedom for customization, is to create your own widget to render your `ChoiceField` without a `<select>`/`<option>` logic, but for example a `<ul>`/`<li>` one, as in the Bootstrap dropdowns. Some pointers [here](https://vegibit.com/how-to-create-and-use-custom-form-fields-and-widgets-in-django/).

Comment: Thank you so much, I will definitely try this.